# docker exec bash in windows - keyboard arrow keys don't work

Tags: windows, bash, keyboard, docker, boot2docker

I've always just used `boot2docker ssh` and in that I'd run

```
    docker exec -it container bash
```

and it would work fine.

Now I'm using the new windows client and while `docker exec -it container bash` will get me to a bash prompt, from there if I type, left/right/up/down/home/end/page up/page down won't work.  Not sure what windows is missing in it's config to not properly work with those keys.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly, either terminal properties get changed (try comparing `stty -g` output, with/without docker) or the readline behavior changes (see if `rlwrap` helps), when you run it via docker.

Comment: A long shot:  try `set -o emacs`.

Comment: stty -g shows the same thing when in the container with exec bash in windows or boot2docker.  stty freezes git bash in windows, but in cmd it returns a different line.

Answer (score 4):

try
`/bin/bash`
within shell before doing anything else.

It always work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

While it does not seem possible to configure docker, as a workaround, you can symlink sh to bash inside the container, so that bash is used by default, supporting arrow key actions:

```
ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Also see

[How to change the default /bin/sh to /bin/bash on opening CLI for selected container in Docker Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617354/how-to-change-the-default-bin-sh-to-bin-bash-on-opening-cli-for-selected-conta)