# How to enable arrow keys for Docker Desktop CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, docker-desktop

I am able to start a command line interface (CLI) for a distinct docker container from within Docker Desktop:

[image]

If I press an arrow key inside the console window, strange character codes are shown, e.g.
if I press the up key, instead of showing the last command, the characters
"^[[A" are shown:

[image]

=> How can I permanently adapt the shell command?

I tried to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the system environment variables to use `bash` instead `sh` but that did not help.

**Related:**

[docker exec bash in windows - keyboard arrow keys don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634044/docker-exec-bash-in-windows-keyboard-arrow-keys-dont-work)

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2457

Comment: As a workaround, its possible to enter /bin/bash in the sh CLI. Then the arrow keys work as expected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For **support of arrow keys** one needs `bash` instead of `sh`. However, bash is not supported by all docker images. I guess that's why docker does not have a configuration option to use bash as a default.

If bash is installed for a specific container, you can `symlink` `sh` to `bash` inside the container, so that `bash` is used by default. Open a container console and type:

```
ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Close the console and open it again. **Now you are using bash, supporting arrow key actions.**

It's possible to include that in the *docker image* as well.

Also see:

[How to change the default /bin/sh to /bin/bash on opening CLI for selected container in Docker Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617354/how-to-change-the-default-bin-sh-to-bin-bash-on-opening-cli-for-selected-conta)

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/symbolic-link-linux

Comment: that's a really handy trick, tyvm! now I am finally able to use a .bashrc as I used to, under /root/.bashrc

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.  The behavior remains the same.  When I change to the root account, I can up arrow to commands in my history.  When I'm not in the root account, I can't.

Answer (score 97):

I was running **CLI** from **Docker** GUI faced the same issue. ***Solved***

1. From opened **CLI** run below command
2. `/bin/bash`
3. Then this will see: **root@630bc9d304e5:~#**
4. Now you can use Arrow Keys

I hope it will work .

Comment: Is it possible to make this change permanent?

Comment: I don't know yet

Comment: Well, that describes the workaround, that I already mentioned above but is not really an answer.

Comment: Yes, its possible to make the change permanent (for individual containers, see answer)